# GDI+ draws letters bunched together

Tags: c++, fonts, gdi+, typography, kerning

I feel like I've read a question similar to this but I can't find it, so please close if duplicate.

I am trying to draw text with `Graphics::DrawString` with a monospace font (Consolas). However, when I draw the text, the letters are not evenly spaced. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the letters are clustered into groups of two and three. I read [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307208) and I thought I had taken adequate steps to avoid it by using `StringFormat::GenericTypographic`, but apparently not. I am also using `TextRenderingHintClearTypeGridFit` because all the others look like junk (and there's no `TextRenderingHintClearType` without the `GridFit` part).

How can I draw text like all the other programs that draw text with a monospace font so that it looks right?

Comment: This is a known problem with Graphics.DrawString().  That's why the TextRenderer class became available in .NET 2.0, it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not using .NET

Comment: Well, use DrawTextEx() then, same thing.

Comment: @HansPassant that's part of GDI, no? Does it do antialiasing, cleartype, and all that?

Comment: Whatever is selected as the operating system default.  Yes.

Comment: @HansPassant if you would post that as an answer I'd be glad to accept it

Comment: The issue is that GDI+ uses a different (and long since abandoned) system for drawing text. Starting with .NET framework 2.0, Microsoft changed all the controls to actually use **GDI** for text rendering, rather than **GDI+**. Text rendering in GDI is hardware accelerated, and continued to get improvements with character rendering, Uniscribe, ligatures. Text rendering in GDI+ is not hardware accelerated, and not getting any fixes or improvements.

Comment: @IanBoyd good to know. For some reason I always read that GDI+ is good for rendering text. I guess I can use GDI+ for some drawing for its antialiasing capabilities and plain GDI for text.

Comment: GDI can also draw anti-aliased, use `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY` or `ANTIALIASED_QUALITY`. See my screenshots in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6404811/12597 for examples.

Comment: @IanBoyd wow that's an awesome answer. If you'd care to post an answer in this question too I'd upvote and mark it as the answer if Hans Passant doesn't answer in a while.

Comment: Those definitely look evenly-spaced to me... Maybe it's my monitor? Or perhaps my eyes? Anyway, Hans and Ian are right, GDI is a better solution for drawing text regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that GDI+ uses a different (and long since abandoned) system for drawing text. Starting with .NET framework 2.0, Microsoft changed all the controls to actually use GDI for text rendering, rather than GDI+. Text rendering in GDI is hardware accelerated, and continued to get improvements with character rendering, Uniscribe, ligatures. Text rendering in GDI+ is not hardware accelerated, and not getting any fixes or improvements.

GDI can also draw anti-aliased, use CLEARTYPE_QUALITY or ANTIALIASED_QUALITY.

Here's a comparison of

- GDI+ (`Graphics.DrawString`)
- GDI (`TextRenderer.DrawText`)

[image]