# Proper Measurement of Characters in Pixels

Tags: c++, clr, gdi+, command-line-interface

I'm writing a text box from scratch in order to optimize it for syntax highlighting. However, I need to get the width of characters in pixels, exactly, not the garbage Graphics::MeasureString gives me. I've found a lot of stuff on the web, specifially [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2118/Bypass-Graphics-MeasureString-limitations), however, none of it seems to work, or does not account for tabs. I need the fastest way to measure the exact dimensions of a character in pixels, and tab spaces. I can't seem to figure this one out...

Should mention I'm using C++, CLR/CLI, and GDI+

---

Here is my measuring function. In another function the RectangleF it returns is drawn to the screen:

```
RectangleF TextEditor::MeasureStringWidth(String^ ch, Graphics^ g, int xDistance, int lineYval)
{
    RectangleF measured;
    Font^ currentFont = gcnew Font(m_font, (float)m_fontSize);
    StringFormat^ stringFormat = gcnew StringFormat;
    RectangleF layout = RectangleF(xDistance,lineYval,35,m_fontHeightPix);
    array<CharacterRange>^ charRanges = {CharacterRange(0,1)};
    array<Region^>^ strRegions;

    stringFormat->FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags::DirectionVertical;
    stringFormat->SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(charRanges);

    strRegions = g->MeasureCharacterRanges(ch, currentFont, layout, stringFormat);

    if(strRegions->Length >= 1)
        measured = strRegions[0]->GetBounds(g);
    else
        measured = RectangleF(0,0,0,0);

    return measured;
}
```

I don't really understand what MeasureCharacterRanges layoutRect parameter does. I modified the code from Microsofts example to only work with, or only measure, one character.

Comment: Measuring just one character is wrong, that's why you get bad results.  Because of kerning, the extent of a string is not even close to the sum of extents of individual characters.  If you want the coordinates of each character, pass the entire string, and set up a `CharacterRange` for each character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be using `Graphics` for any text rendering.

Starting with .NET Framework 2.0 use of `Graphics.MeasureString` and `Graphics.DrawString` was deprecated in favor of a newly added helper class `TextRenderer`:

- `TextRenderer.MeasureText`
- `TextRenderer.DrawText`

The GDI+ text renderer has been abandoned, and hasn't gotten any improvements or fixes for over 10 years; as well as being software rendered.

GDI rendering (which `TextRenderer` is a simple wrapper of) is hardware accelerated, and continues to get rendering improvements (ligatures, Uniscribe, etc).

**Note:** GDI+ text rendering is wrapped by `Graphics.DrawString` and `MeasureString`

Here's a comparison of the measure results of `Graphics` and `TextRenderer`:

[image]

The GDI+ measurements aren't *"wrong"*, they are doing exactly what they intend - return the size that the text would be *if* it were rendered as the original font author intended (which you can achieve using *Anti-alias rendering*):

[image]

But nobody really *wants* to look at text the way the font designer intended, because that causes stuff to not line-up on pixel boundaries - making the text too fuzzy (i.e. as you see on a Mac). Ideally the text should be snapped to line up on actual *pixel boundaries* (i.e. Windows' **Grid Fitting**)

### Bonus Reading

- [See my answer over here, with more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6404811/12597)

Comment: Good answer; very much agreed about preferring GDI to GDI+. That's something Win32 developers have known for a long time, the WinForms team was just a bit slow to come around. `TextRenderer` has been around now for enough versions to assume it's ubiquitously available. But I think someone stole the second half of your last sentence!

Comment: Wow, I had never even heard of TextRenderer! Thank you, I should probably find my answer with this.

Comment: @CodyGray That was me inserting my final bonus chatter link before some half-completed thought; that should have been removed. It has been removed :)

Answer (score 2):

There's [`MeasureCharacterRanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges.aspx) that is like `MeasureString`, but more powerful and more accurate (and also slower).

Comment: I rewrote my measuring function with this, however, it seems to ignore whitespaces and all the measurements come out inaccurate. I'll post my code.