# Resizing bitmap to draw string

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to draw string in a Bitmap like this:

```
Font myfont=new Font("TimesNewRoman",18)
Bitmap bmpBitmap =new Bitmap(200,100);
Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(bmpBitmap);
g.DrawString("SampleText",myfont,Brushes.Black);
```

How do I determine the size of bitmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following function to measure the size of a `string` with respect to a certain `Font`.

[`SizeF Graphics.MeasureString(string text, Font font)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

Also, ensure the `TextRenderingHint` for the `Graphics` is set to `AntiAlias`. This makes a world of difference when it comes to the readability of the text.

---

If you want to measure a `string` **before** you create your `Bitmap`, use the solution presented over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1003503/1828879

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`bmpBitmap.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.size.aspx) to get both Height and Width, or
`bmpBitmap.Height` and `bmpBitmap.Width` to get one or the other?