# C# Listview making columns size equal to half of listview width

Tags: c#, listview, user-interface

I have a listview object that I want to have 2 columns. I want the two columns to stretch across the width of the listview and to have both column headers centered in each column. If I set the size of the columns to -2 (auto size), I get the following result (code followed by screenshot):

```
        this.recipList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 32);
        this.recipList.Name = "recipList";
        this.recipList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(376, 296);
        this.recipList.TabIndex = 1;
        this.recipList.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.recipList.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        this.recipList.Columns.Add("Recipient", -2, System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        this.recipList.Columns.Add("Number of Reports", -2, System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center);
```

[image]

If I drag the columns manually within this window to mimic what I WANT to have, I get this. the only issue here is that even with `Recipient` set to `HorizontalAlignment.Center` it still left-aligns after I drag it to where I want it:

[image]

At this point I figure that the way to get both columns to span across the entire width of the listview box and for each column to take up half of it, I simply need to set the size of each column to 1/2 of the width of the entire listview. So I do this:

```
        this.recipList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 32);
        this.recipList.Name = "recipList";
        this.recipList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(376, 296);
        this.recipList.TabIndex = 1;
        this.recipList.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.recipList.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        this.recipList.Columns.Add("Recipient", 188, System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        this.recipList.Columns.Add("Number of Reports", 188, System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center);
```

Since 188 is 1/2 of 376. This produces the following result:

[image]

As you can see, it almost worked with 2 issues.

1. The `Number of Reports` column spans off of the listview box and creates a scrollbar. I don't want this.
2. Recipient is still left-aligned even though it is set to `HorizontalAlignment.Center`.

Is there a better way to approach these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can create Headers for your ListView :

```
ColumnHeader headerFirst;
ColumnHeader headerSecond;
headerFirst = new ColumnHeader();
headerSecond = new ColumnHeader();

// Set the text, alignment and width for each column header.
headerFirst.Text = "Recipient";
headerFirst.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
headerFirst.Width = 188;

headerSecond.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
headerSecond.Text = "Number of Reports";
headerSecond.Width = 188;

// Add the headers to the ListView control.
ListView1.Columns.Add(headerFirst);
ListView1.Columns.Add(headerSecond);
```

It's explain on the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The Width is the outer width of the ListView and includes the border pixels. Count them for your borderstyle and make your columns a bit smaller. Or if you want to do it *right* use the ClientSize property [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The first column in a ListView is left aligned by design *afaik*; so to simulate a centered header you could pad it with spaces to the left. To do this in a precise manner you will have to measure the Text length using the given Font. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003370/measure-a-string-without-using-a-graphics-object). Or count the letters and be happy with less presision. Or, I guess, you could go with a hack and add a dummy first column..