# Pdf landscape orientation using MeasureString

Tags: c#, pdf, graphics, wkhtmltopdf, export-to-pdf

I am using wkHTMLtoPDF and I want to change orientation on the PDF based on the length of the headers in the HTML, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do this.

```
private const double A4Width = 2480; // A4 pixel width
```

Landscape detection method

```
private bool IsLandscape(string html)
{
     int start = html.IndexOf("<th>");
     int end = html.LastIndexOf("</th>") - start;
     string tableHeadings = html.Substring(start, end).Replace("<th>", string.Empty).Replace("</th>", string.Empty);

     FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
     Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 13);

     var size = MeasureString(tableHeadings, font);

     if(size.Width > A4Width)
     {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Method for font calculus

```
private SizeF MeasureString(string content, Font font)
{
     SizeF result = SizeF.Empty;

     using (var image = new Bitmap(1,1))
     {
         using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
         {
            g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            result = g.MeasureString(content, font, int.MaxValue, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
         }
     }
     return result;
}
```

Note: This code is in a library so that is the reason I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003370/measure-a-string-without-using-a-graphics-object/1003503#1003503) question to measure string.

**Update**

***To be short:***

I am looking for a best practice of implementing the problem.

***The problem summary:***

I am building from HTML a PDF that has a table inside. 
I get the table columns (eg: Col1, Col2) and remove the tags (eg: Col1Col2).
Next I want to calculate the size (in px) of that string result (using a Font with a specified text size), and if that size excedes the A4 portrait size than rotate the PDF to the landscape orientation.

Comment: Hi, sorry can you please extend your question, I did not understand Your Problem. Are you looking a best practice exactly for what?

Comment: I have updated the question. Feel free to ask if you don't understand something. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't found an exact exact solution but below I have found some informations about how to find the actual printable area.
I hope it could help you dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the best implementation of this problem is to add to wkHTMLtoPDF an attribute to force the PDF to be A4 size.

Attribute used : `--page-size A4`

Also I have changed the code that checks if the measured width size is grater than the A4 size.

```
if(size.Width > (A4Width / 4))
{
    return true;
}
```